# Fast SQL Server search on 40M text records

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have a SQL Server 2005 database with a table containing 40 million records. Each record contains a column that stores a comma separated list of keywords. Each keyword is a combination of letters and numbers. The keywords are up to 7 characters long and on average there are 15 keywords per record. The keywords are not unique across rows.

I want to search on full or part of the keyword.

I've created Full text index which shows 328,245,708 unique key count. The search efficiency is fine for queries of 4 or more characters (around **100ms** on the test machine), but too slow for queries that have 3 or less characters (up to **3s** on the test machine).

I've been trying both `CONTAINSTABLE` and `CONTAINS` queries of a sort `'[query]*'` with similar result.

I believe the performance of the short queries is slower, because short words repeat across different records more frequently.

Sorting the results is not crucial, and I've been trying to return `TOP X` results sorted on Rank from `CONTAINSTABLE`. This doesn't provide the desired performance.

How can I make this search faster for short queries?

Comment: I would reconstruct the table structure, make a new table with the keywords and refer it back to the primary key in the original table using a foreign key

Comment: I'm with t-clausen.dk.  You could create a table with an ID for each distinct keyword, then create a table with rowID/KeywordID pairs, and a one-to-many relationship between your existing table and the pairs table.

Comment: Would that present a performance gain over Full Text Index on the keywords column? Also that way I would face a problem of duplicate results possibility while search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to gateway it to something like [SOLR](http://lucene.apache.org/solr) or [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com) and let a dedicated text-search engine handle the search functionality.

Comment: What range of performance gain should I expect in comparision to Sql Server Full Text Index

Comment: @MRT perhaps a quick google (or a bing) search would be useful in this case?

Comment: How do you propose I utilize Google search for that purpose?

Comment: SOLR vs. Sphinx vs. SQL Server full-text search perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in right direction. Couldn't find any actual comparison data but have implemented SOLR and most likely I'll stick with this solution. I was able to index my 40 million records DB that allows now for even 1 character searches in the middle of the word (much more detailed index than what I had on SQL Server) and it searches pretty efficiently on the same test machine. The query times are pretty uniform no matter how long the search query is - around 1s (again, with index being much more thorough than the one I had previously in SQL Server).

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to consider normalizing the table structure so that you would have your data records in one table, your tags in another table, and an associative table to relate the tags to the data records.  This would allow you to perform the text search against the tags and simply join on the associative table to retrieve the relevant records.

Comment: Would that have any performance benefit over Full Text Index on the keywords column?

Comment: Absolutely.  Another benefit to breaking the tags out into a separate table is that you could create an index on the tag name.  This would provide perhaps the most profound impact upon the text search.

Comment: Isn't it how Full Text Index words behind the scene - creating a lookup table with all the tags (words)?

Comment: You are confusing the concept of a [Full Text Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search) with the concept of a [Database Index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index).