# Efficeint search on huge MySQL database

Tags: android, mysql, search, indexing

I have 300 millions of records of contact details of people. I am planning to store this data in MySQL database. I am going to develop the Android App which will accept mobile number and will display details of person matching this mobile number. Will it be enough just to have index on mobile number field if I store whole the data in single table? Or will it be good to split data into multiple tables depending on mobile number? I am thinking to slit data into multiple tables as :

---

Table1 will contain records whose mobile numbers starts with 91

Table2 will contain records whose mobile numbers starts with 92

Table3 will contain records whose mobile numbers starts with 93

                        .

                        .

                        .

so and so forth.

I am thinking like this because we can reduce almost 70%+ comparisons.

---

Please give your valuable comments and suggestions on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. It is not a bad question.

Comment: Won't let me edit so I'm posting again. I don't have a definitive answer but I don't know that splitting the data is necessarily a good idea. If you're associating numbers with users you still need to associate those 300mm entries with individuals. Breaking the tables into numbers with 91, 92, etc, sounds like it would make that unmanagble and searching the database more difficult. You have to look at the bigger picture when trying to decompose relations. This may solve one need but make other things harder.

Answer (score 0):

it seems creating separate table with keywords would be efficient. Moreover you can refer this thread for details,

[Most efficient way to search a database with more than a billion records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17287184/most-efficient-way-to-search-a-database-with-more-than-a-billion-records)

Answer (score 0):

300 M of records - can peacefully exist in 1 table. 
before planning to split the data - try it on your hardware and check the results.
If the performance of 1 table is insufficient - you can also try "partitioning" inside the mysql Db, which will simplify your application and give you a performance of separate tables.